# Conditional css selector

Tags: css, conditional-statements

I have two elements A and B. I want to select only one of those. If both the elements are there it should return A. If A is not there then and then only it should return B. Suppose element A has class ".A" and B has ".B".

e.g.

```html
<div class="B"> Element B </div>
```

`$(.A/.B)`  should return Element B

and for

```
<div class="A"> Element A </div>
<div class="B"> Element B </div>
```

it should return Element A.

How to do this using css selector

Comment: Please provide your *HTML* markup. It's pretty hard to find a css selector without seeing the markup.

Comment: CSS is not "conditional"...you select something and style it...that's it. Perhaps you could clarify your actual requirement.

Comment: I think you want to use this selector in jQuery. am I right?

Comment: CSS cannot 'select' or 'return' **content** as your code / requirement seems to suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood you question, so I try. Example with backgrounds:

```
.A, .B {background: blue}
.A + .B {background: transparent}
```

When there is only `.B` element, it will be blue.
When there are both, `.A` followed by `.B`, blue background is set to `.A`, `.B` is transparent.

http://jsfiddle.net/fbjwy7hm/ (both `.A` and `.B`, background style is applied to the first el. only)
http://jsfiddle.net/fbjwy7hm/1/ (`.B` only, background style is applied here)

Comment: I have two elements A and B. I want to select only one of those.  If both the elements are there it should return A. If A is not there then and then only it should return B.  Suppose element A has class ".A" and B has ".B".

Comment: @ManojMali: CSS hasn't `or` selector. CSS knows children and siblings selectors only, and it works as I wrote above. No other choice how to differ these elements doesn't exist. Just, you can change `+` for `~` to find all next siblings. Here you can see, CSS know siblings, but only next siblings. Previous siblings, reverse to `.A + .B` doesn't exist too.